# .babelrc configuration placed in package.JSON

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, package.json

Currently exploring webpack different tools associated with it. Now I am using Babel for transpiling `ES6` code into `ES5` code. I came accross the need for a `.babelrc` file which holds the configurations for Babel. However, on the website of Babel I also saw that you could also place these configurations into the `package.json` file. Like this:

**Package.json File:**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ]
  }

}
```

Now when I run `npm run dev` Babel also works and the code gets transpiled succesfully.

How does Babel know to access the package.json file? Does it first look for an `.babelrc` file and then if this is not present does it automatically look for its configurations in the `package.json`? How does Webpack interact with both `Babel` and the `package.json` file to produce this result?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc#lookup-behavior

Comment: Okay thanks that is clear!!

Answer (score 19):

For anyone who is interested it was on the [official website:](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc#lookup-behavior)

> Babel will look for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file
>   being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the
>   directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json
>   with a "babel": {} hash within.

Comment: From my experience, even an empty or completely commented out .babelrc file will prevent babel from looking in the package.json.